# Using ArcGIS ModelBuilder and GeoCoding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, geocoding

I looked at ArcGIS and python and I'm not quite ready for that as I'm on a schedule. I have a little experience but not at the level to pick it up quickly enough for my time frame.

The model runs well, I've munged the tables so the geocoder picks up all the fields properly. But I can't get it to save the results of each geocoding process to an individual file.  It just keeps overwriting the same file.

[image]

I tried connecting the name variable to the geocode addresses function but get this:
[image]

Which doesn't work.

Any suggestions how I can get this done?

If there's a simple edit in scripting outside of the ModelBuilder I can do that.

Comment: May need to look at [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000005000000) to gather results to write to one file rather than overwriting each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the second example in [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/). Most probably your question is related to finding the right term here, which is **inline variable substitution**.